# Activity.isFinishing() return true but is wrong

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

Before I show a dialog I check if activity is finishing to avoid the app crash.

```
if(!activity.isFinishing()){
    showDialog();
}
```

but on some cases it returns true but the activity is not finishing and I can continue using my app but when I try to show a dialog it says the activity is finishing.

In what scenario can it happen?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Why do you do that at all? I don't get what problem you're trying to solve...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid BadTokenException when dialog.show() is called

Comment: @YGHM could you perhaps catch the BadTokenException instead?

Comment: @CrimsonSage but then the dialog still would not be shown, so I still need a solution for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was the problem for me.

the class that checked `if(!activity.isFinishing())` is a `Singletone` and in some cases when the app went to the background the `Activity` was closed and when the app came back to foreground a new `Activity` was created and the old activity was still in the `Singletone` and wasn't updated.

so I made sure the `Singletone` updated the `Activity` in that case.

hope it helps anyone.

Comment: Can you please explain how you solved the problem? I am getting the same error but I cannot resolve it

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
if(!activity.isDestroyed()) {
    showDialog();
   }
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

i thought you may have problem in dialog
check your dialog:

```
if(mDialog.isShowing||mDialog.!=null){mDialog.finish();}
```